Can orthogonality of features be established by observing changes in the loss function?
Say I have a regression or classification problem and collect a large amount of data.  My hypothesis is that if I choose $2$ orthogonal (or perhaps orthonormal?) features, then each feature should decrease the loss by some numeric amount invariant of which order they're introduced.  For example, if I start with the empty feature set and incorporating Feature A decreases the loss by $10$, then if I start with Feature B incorporating Feature A should also decrease the loss by $10$, if and only if Feature A and Feature B are orthogonal.  I probably got this intuition from the fact that probabilistic independence means $\Pr(A)\Pr(B) = \Pr(A\ |\ B)\Pr(B)$, and loss functions seem to be more or less a conceptual generalization of probability (the $0-1$ loss would be a probability if divided by the maximum possible loss).
Alternatively, I was hypothesizing that I might need to feed uniform random data to the features as part of a test for their orthogonality.
Is anything in this ballpark true, at least under certain conditions, or do you always have to use the correlation matrix or similar tools to determine orthogonality?

As it stands, there's not enough background about what type of analysis you have in mind for this idea to be wrong or right. Do you have supervised learning via linear models in mind? If so, then there's something intuitively reasonable within what you're suggesting, but the major component missing from your analysis is the relationship between these features and the response: if there's absolutely no relationship between feature B and the response, then it's not going to be useful for the model even if it is orthogonal to A.

@JohnMadden I did have supervised learning in mind.  I wasn't necessarily thinking just linear models, but it does make sense that there might be an extra step if the model isn't linear, such as plugging the loss functions into the kernel function in the case of a kernelized model to transform the losses into a linear scale.
